# Ubuntu Bash Script changing file names chronologicaly

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have this bash script where I am trying to change all *.txt files in a directory to their date of last modification. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Renames the .txt files to the date modified
# FROM: foo.txt  Created on: 2012-04-18 18:51:44
# TO:    20120418_185144.txt
for i in *.txt
do
mod_date=$(stat --format %y "$i"|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'|cut -f1 -d'.'|sed 's/[: -]//g') 
mv "$i" "$mod_date".txt
done
```

The error I am getting is:

```
renamer.sh: 6: renamer.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The `for ... do` looks OK but you're missing the end of the expression in  `mod_date=$(...`, perhaps this is affecting the parsing of the script?

Comment: Sorry about that, question fixed.

Comment: Weird.. I run your script and it works

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with file permissions?

Comment: Which file bring the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm always amazed to see how people can get really smart at piping `grep`s through `sed`s through `awk`s through `cut`s through `head`s and `tail`s...

In your particular case, you're really lucky because the `date` command can format the modification date of a file (with the `-r` option)!

Thus,

```
#!/bin/bash

# It's a good idea to use one of the two:
shopt -s failglob
# shopt -s nullglob

for i in *.txt; do
    mod_date=$(date -r "$i" +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    mv "$i" "$mod_date.txt"
done
```

should do the trick.

Regarding `nullglob` or `failglob`: If there's no file that matches `*.txt`, then the script just exits with an error (when using `failglob`), or, if using `nullglob`, nothing happens, since in this case `*.txt` expands to nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I haven't tested it since I moved away from renaming files by date and time, but it seems like yours would work, so I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code pasted is not complete. Compare the code below with your code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Renames the .txt files to the date modified
# FROM: foo.txt  Created on: 2012-04-18 18:51:44
# TO:    20120418_185144.txt
for i in *.txt
do
    mod_date=$(stat --format %y "$i"|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'|cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/[: -]//g')
    mv "$i" "${mod_date}.txt"
done
```

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter since $mod_date can never have spaces. Thus $mod_date.txt with neither double quotes nor curly braces would work too.